# Como comparar email e palavra passes de textboxs com a base de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, comparação

Eu já tenho este código:

```
   <?php
   ...
   $dbconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)or die("Failed to connect to database:" . mysqli_error($conn));

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST['login']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST['senha']);

    if (!empty($email) && !empty($password))
    {

    $query = "SELECT (email, password) FROM Paciente WHERE email = '$email' AND password = SHA('$password') ";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
    $result = mysqli_num_rows($dbname);
    printf("Number of rows %d \n", $result);
    if ($result == 1) {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
        $email = $row('login');
        $password = $row('senha');
        header("location: marcar_consulta_online.html");
    } else {

        echo "A password e/ou email estão erradas";
    }

    }
    else
    {

        echo ' Deve preencher com o seu email e password';
        ?>

    <?php
    }
    mysqli_close($dbcon);
    ?>

   no outro código tenho: 

   <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    <p style="font-size: 20px"> <font face= "Verdana">
        Email:<INPUT type="text" name="login" size=35><br><br>
        Password:<INPUT type="password" name="senha" size=30>
    </p></font>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="botao_login" class="botao_login"/></FORM>
```

Quando carrego no botão ele escreve a mensagem:'Deve preencher com o seu email e password' que só devia acontecer no caso de os campos estarem vazios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só faltou corrigir

`$POST['senha']`

em `$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $POST['senha']);`

para

`$_POST['senha']`

Correto

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST['login']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST['senha']);
```

Comment: Neste não é necessário? $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST['login']);

Comment: essa linha está correta $_POST['login']);  na da senha que faltou o traço de sublinhado ou underline

Answer (score 0):

<s>Você está misturando funções mysqli_ e mysql_, não faça isso!</s>

Também não é recomendado criar os SQLs assim, apesar de você usar o mysqli_real_escape_string. O recomendado é utilizar [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), que aliás faz isso pra você automaticamente.

Outra coisa, não guarde as senhas em formato de texto na base de dados. Se algum invasor conseguir acesso na base de dados, terá todas as senhas e e-mails facilmente. Saiba mais procurando no google por "php gerando hash de senha", já que não posso por mais de 2 links ainda na resposta.

<s>Sobre o erro, se você pesquisar na documentação do método, verá [um comentário](http://$dbconn%20=%20mysqli_connect($servername,%20$username,%20$password,%20$dbname);):</s>

> <s>Note, that if no connection is open, mysqli_real_escape_string() will return an empty string!</s>

Se olhar o código atentamente

```
$dbconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
...
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST['login']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $POST['senha']);
```

<s>verá que você declarou primeiro uma variável $dbco**nn** e tentou usar uma $dbco**n**, no caso o erro é esse.</s>

verá que usou $POST, sem o "_", na linha da senha

Comment: Já alterei o problema de estar a misturar funções e também as variáveis, mas o problema continua na mesma... Editei a pergunta de como ficou o código, não melhorei a criação das SQL pois não percebi muito bem como aquilo funciona, vou ter que estudar bem o link que me disponibilizou.

Comment: sobre hash recomendo a leitura desse [artigo](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografia-no-php-usando-md5-sha1-e-base64) e entre as 3 opções recomendo sha1

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/faq.passwords.php - um dos tópicos do link é porque não devemos usar funções como md5 e sha1 para isso

Comment: Alguém saberá porque mesmo colocando os dado corretos, ele diz que o email e ou a passe estão errados?